# Does jQuery or Chrome memoize function calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm seeing a strange behavior with jQuery on Chrome (Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on Mac). I cannot reproduce it reliably, but I've seen it a few times now and I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong or if I found a bug and if I did, which library/application has the bug? Here's a screenshot of a developer console demonstrating the issue:

[image]

Update: in summary, here's what I did: I assigned a value to `x`. Then I call `$(x)` and it throws an exception. Then I do some other things that should have no effect on the value of `x` (`$(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)))` and `$(String(x))` both succeed), and after that `$(x)` works. This seems like it should be impossible unless jQuery or Chrome are caching (a.k.a. memoizing) function calls and/or strings or DOM objects behind the scenes.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What did you expect and what actually happened?

Comment: I'd suggest using the uncompressed version of jQuery to try to trace this.

Comment: @lonesomeday I can't reproduce this reliably, so haven't been able to capture it in an uncompressed version of jQuery.

Comment: @millerdev I realise that would make it tricky. The answer would seem to be that the string does not match the regex for HTML strings (`/^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]+))$/`), but I can't see how JSON stringify & parse could correct that.

Comment: You don't happen to have some invisible characters in that string? Or some denormalised unicode stuff?

Comment: @Bergi nope. `x` does not change between the first `$(x)` call and the last one, but they have different results.

Comment: @millerdev I suppose therefore it only could be a bug in the internal handling of strings (where the `String(x)` operation causes it to change the representation), and that might be triggered by weird characters (assuming the bug would not have lasted long if it affected common strings). I think you definitely should report this as a Chrome bug, but you'll need to provide your `auto_box` function to give a reproducible example.